# what is efficient linear search algorithm on an ordered integer array?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

what is efficient linear search algorithm on an ordered integer array? and what is the average-case time complexity A(n) when assume that all 2n+1 events(why?)  are equally probable?

Answer (score 0):

The standard search algorithm on an ordered array
Is the binary search which has logarithmic time.

I'm not sure what you mean by a linear search algorithm.

I seem to recall reading many years ago that if you do an interpolatory binary search that the average time will be
log log n.